# How to set the minimum length of text so that the knockout autocomplete control is shown?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, autocomplete, knockout-mvc

I am using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout library to bind autocomplete to textbox in my asp mvc application as follow:

```
var myCustomBinding = "...";
var text = knockoutHtml.Hidden();
text.Items.Add(new KnockoutBindingStringItem("autocomplete", myCustomBinding));
```

The default behavior of knockout autocomplete is firing the autocomplete field immediately after the first character was typed. I want to customize this behavior to force knockout autocomplete control to fire autocomplete field after 3 characters were typed. I don't want to validate text if there are a minimum of 3 characters typed.

I search [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56608560/minimal-symbols-amount-for-data-upload-in-autocomplete) but I only need to show autocomplete after the third character was typed I don't need any other custom additional behavior.

What I must bind to knockout autocomplete (in myCustomBinding variable)? How to set the minimum length of search text?

Comment: show us your autocomplete binding handler code.

Comment: the bounty you put would be in vain if you won't add your autocomplete code. please add it.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".buttonclass").typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        //your source code
    },
    items: 10,
    autoSelect: false,
    minLength: 3,
    hint: true, //to highlight matching item
    highlight: true,
    afterSelect: function (item) {
        //your code
    },
    matcher: () => {
        return true;
    },
});
```

Comment: Hi ElConrado are you get your answer?